# multicount on SQl query

Tags: mysql, sql, count, multiple-instances

I am looking for the proper SQl query to pull data from a the database and COUNT the specific rows to come up with a total... here's my table:

```
------------------------------------------
|name     |App      |Dep       |Sold     |
------------------------------------------
|Joe      |1        |1         |2        |
|Joe      |1        |2         |2        |
|Steve    |1        |1         |1        |
|Steve    |1        |2         |1        |
------------------------------------------
```

So I need to count the "1" in each column for each name and come up and output the totals like this:

```
Joe    |  2 App  |  1 Dep  | 0 Sold
Steve  |  2 App  |  1 Dep  | 2 Sold
```

Anyone have a starting point for me?  I'm not sure if i need JOINs or i can just add seperate COUNTs for each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  Name,
        SUM(App = 1) TotalApp,
        SUM(Dep = 1) TotalDep,
        SUM(Sold = 1) TotalSold
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93fb9/1)

`App = 1` is a mysql specific syntax which performs boolean arithmetic resulting `1 and 0`. To make it more RDBMS friendly, you can use `CASE` eg. `SUM(CASE WHEN App = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`.

- [SQL Fiddle Demo using CASE statement](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93fb9/2)

Comment: And TotalApp, etc.. would just be called as $TotalApp to echo?

Comment: Got it $row['TotalApp']